# hover over two elements set effect to one element

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-hover

I have this list item in my nav , It has a dropDown menu

```
 <li class="projects">
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <ul class="list-unstyled myDropDown">
             <li><a href="#">King SALEH Bridge</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Internationl future schools</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Elwakeel Companies Group</a></li>
      </ul>
 </li>
```

and here is the styles

```
nav .myDropDown{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-height:160px;
    background-color:#ffb700;
    top:calc(15px + 100%)
}
```

and I want to display .myDropDown when hovering on li.projects and it still displayed when hovering on .myDropDown itself , and it disappear when the mouse became not in li.projects or .myDropDown .

I have this jquery code , but it doesn't work ?!

```
 $("nav .projects").hover(function(){
     $("nav .myDropDown").css("display","block");
 });
 $("nav .myDropDown").hover(function(){
           $(this).css("display","block");
  },function(){
           $(this).css("display","none");
 });
```

Comment: why u just don't use pure css for that?

Comment: your nav is not included in the OP

Comment: I tried to do so but it doesnt work ..                                                        nav ul li.projects:hover .myDropDown{
    display:block
}
nav .myDropDown:hover{
    display:block
}

Comment: @guradio nav ul li.projects is a children like its siblings list items to the parent nav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use the CSS answers provided. But if you want to use javascript you should do it like this:

```
 $("nav .projects").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".myDropDown").css("display","block");
 }, function(){
     $(this).find(".myDropDown").css("display","none");
 });
```

You can't keep the `top:calc(15px + 100%)` if you want it to overlap. If you keep a gap between the dropdown and the link you're removing it before entering it. It's the same with the CSS solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/80tbzcjh/1/

Comment: thanks dude I appreciate your answer , it's very useful , it works fine                     https://jsfiddle.net/80tbzcjh/2/

Answer (score 2):

Why not only CSS?

```css
ul.myDropDown{
  display: none;
}

li.projects:hover > ul.myDropDown{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li class="projects">
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <ul class="list-unstyled myDropDown">
             <li><a href="#">King SALEH Bridge</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Internationl future schools</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Elwakeel Companies Group</a></li>
      </ul>
 </li>
```

EDIT: I changed your top value and it works:

```css
li.projects {
 position: relative; 
}

ul.myDropDown{
  display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-height:160px;
    background-color:#ffb700;
    top: 0px;
}

li.projects:hover > ul.myDropDown{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li class="projects">
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <ul class="list-unstyled myDropDown">
             <li><a href="#">King SALEH Bridge</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Internationl future schools</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Elwakeel Companies Group</a></li>
      </ul>
 </li>
```

Comment: it doesn't work bro because ul.myDropDown has position absolute and when  hover on li.projects , the dropdown menu displayed , but when hover on the ul.myDropDown itself it disappear because you leaved the mouse on li.projects

Comment: Now with top: 0? The problem is that you were moving it absolutely to the bottom of the page and the gap between both elements is counted as "not hover", so it disappears.

Comment: yes , the problem was in top property , it works fine now thanks alot bro

Answer (score 1):

use this way

```
li:hover .myDropDown{dispaly:block;}
```

Comment: it doesn't work bro because ul.myDropDown has position absolute and when hover on li.projects , the dropdown menu displayed , but when hover on the ul.myDropDown itself it disappear because you leaved the mouse on li.projects